# open file and current directory permissions

Tags: permissions, filesystems

I'm trying to learn about file and directory permissions in unix/linux.

I think I got the general idea, if I want to

```
cat ~/foo/bar/text.txt
```

I need `x+r` permission on `~`, `~/foo`, `~/foo/bar`, and `r` permission on `~/foo/bar/text.txt`.

But let's say I don't have `x` permission on `~/foo/bar` and that somehow my current directory is `~/foo/bar` (maybe `root` user made `su user` there), let's say there I type

```
cat text.txt
```

from my test, it says I don't have permissions even if I have `rwx` on `text.txt`.

So my question is:  When I type

```
cat text.txt
```

does the system really interpret `cat ./text.txt` and so checks the current directory permission as well?  (I thought that the directories I didn't mention in the path wouldn't be checked for permissions, but maybe the current one is checked neitherways?)

So in this case (my current directory is `~/foo/bar` and I want to do `cat text.txt`) the permissions on `~/foo` does not matter but those on `~/foo/bar` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file open operation does require reading its directory entry for its attributes and physical location, which is stored in the current directory (file).

That is why you are getting the permission issue.

Otherwise, your assumptions are right and the system only accesses the path specified.  This would make the file accessible in your `sudo` example if you simply gave `x` access to the local directory.

Note that the `r` permission is not needed to retrieve a directory entry, but it is required to list its contents.